# How to get the current offset position in Rich text box while double click in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, richtextbox

While am going edit mode in Richtext box by double click, the caret position goes either to start or to the end of the text. But in normal text box wherever you double click, the cusrsor in the correct position.

How to change the caret position based on mouse clicking position? here i provided the code what i have tried.

I want to get excel like behavior.

```
TextPointer tp = richtextbox.CaretPosition;
tp = tp.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
richtextbox.Selection.Select(richtextbox.CaretPosition, tp); 

TextPointer start = richtextbox.Document.ContentStart;
TextPointer caret = richtextbox.CaretPosition;
TextRange range = new TextRange(start, caret);
int indexInText = range.Text.Length;
```

I have double clicked near "3" in "12345" highlighted as yellow in snapshot. But the caret blinks at the start position.

[image: snapshot Issue faced]

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429765/set-caret-cursor-position-in-richtextbox-wpf

Comment: I have checked. That article says about changing caret position to content start & end only. But my requirement, caret position should be moved to mouse clicking position. FYI - My RichTextBox is getting edit mode when mouse double clicking.

Comment: so, pls let me know how to get offset value of mouse position to be passed in Document.ContentStart.GetPositionatOffset() method.